# how to let VS Code know the type of the parameter is passed in during Python development

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

as we know Python is a strongly typed language, so you don't pass the parameter type when define a function.
I am currently using VS Code for python development, and When I Define a function, I often know the type of the parameter I pass in so I'd like to let VScode know the parameter type, so it can provide better annotation and auto completion for me. for example

```
import pandas as pd
def function_1 (pd_frame) :
    list = pd_frame.values.tolist()
    return list
```

When i type pd_frame(dot) if VScode knows the type, the I can see all the available methods and attribute pop up
does anyone know how to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: add `type annotations`. don't use a variable that is a name of a build in type `list`, why not use `return pd_frame.values.tolist()`, what is the need for the variable `list`

Comment: who told you Python is a strongly typed language?

Comment: Use Type instead see @rioV8 comment if return type is list of integer then add -> def function_1 (pd_frame) -> List[int]:and you have to import from typing import List

Comment: @rioV8 I do that for the sake of explaining what I need. when When i type pd_frame(dot) if VScode knows the type, I wish VS code can show complete /method list